# Probability of a being at a certain state after some time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, queueing-theory

A system can be in two states, $a$ and $b$. The waiting time for $a$ to become $b$ is modelled by means of an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda,$ $1-e^{-\lambda t},$ and the waiting time for $b$ to become  $a$ is modelled by means of an exponential distribution with parameter $\mu,$ $1-e^{-\mu t}.$

If initially the system is in state $a,$ I'd like to know the probability of the system being in each state after a time $T.$

The exponential distribution gives the probability of a transition happening before time $t,$ but for this particular problem I'd need the probability of the transition taking place exactly at time $t,$ and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: as you are probably aware, what you describe is the most simple example of a (homogeneous) continuous time markov chain.  IIRC its evolution is governed by a matrix differential equation and can be solved explicitly.  you can find lots of results by googling "continuous time markov chain".  e.g. your example is (i think) the same as Example 1 in these lecture notes, but alas, the notes themselves left the derivation as a blank page.  :)  http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~ionides/620/notes/cts_time_markov_chains.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well, I know this can be seen as a Markov chain, yes, but for that I need the transition probabilities per unit time, and that's what I do not know how to calculate from the fact that the life-times are exponential distributions.

Comment: the transition prob per unit time is directly related to the exponential parameter.  these are the best notes i can find, and the 2nd page onward is indeed the 2-state example: http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~amirgi/CTMCnotes.pdf